# Shared Item Transition not working in fragment on back

Tags: android, android-fragments, transition

I'm working on an Android app with the [Fragment Navigation Pattern](https://www.toptal.com/android/android-fragment-navigation-pattern) (one Activity with many Fragments). I've managed to implement *Shared Item Transitions* by following [this guide](https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb) but they **only work going forward, not on hitting back.**

My Fragment (called `UserFragment`) is composed of a `ViewPager` with 3 more fragments with RecyclerViews. Clicking any item in the RecyclerViews opens another `UserFragment` with the same views. The transition works perfectly when switching to the new fragment, but **I'm unable to get it to work when closing it**. When hitting back, the fragment simply fades out and the previous fragment fades in.

### TL;DR:

- The Shared Element in question is the Circular Image View on top
- Its `transitionName` is *profile*
- `SharedItemTransition` is a custom class that extends `TransitionSet`
- I've given each item in each recyclerview unique transition names, by including their user id, list type and position index (and if they weren't unique, it also wouldn't work going forward)

---

Here's the `onBindViewHolder` method of my **RecyclerView Adapter:**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final UserViewHolder uvh, int position) {
    final LocUser user = users.get(position);
    String transition  = "user_" + user.id() + "_type_" + type + "_item_" + position + "_profile_image";

    uvh.name.setText(user.name());
    uvh.username.setText(user.handle());

    Global.setImage(uvh.userImage, user.profileImage());
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(uvh.userImage, transitionName(position));

    uvh.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            activity.openUserProfile(user, uvh.userImage);
        }
    });
}
```

---

Here's my **activity method** that invokes the `FragmentManager` and starts the animation:

```
public void openUserProfile(LocUser user, ImageView view) {
    UserProfileFragment uf = UserProfileFragment.create(user);

    uf.setExitTransition(new Fade());
    uf.setEnterTransition(new Fade());
    uf.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new SharedItemTransition());
    uf.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new SharedItemTransition());

    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .addSharedElement(view, "profile")
        .replace(R.id.container, uf)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
}
```

---

This is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think I have the exact same problem, although mine is an even simpler case. I switch between a list fragment and a detail fragment. The shared element transition works correctly when going forward, but not at all when going back. Have you managed to figure out what was causing this?

Comment: Still haven't been able to fix this...

Comment: @GeorgeMetaxas  : I have the same problem.

Comment: Guys, Any solution for this issue? @TeeTracker

Comment: @shaiban keep the "source" and "target" in same "transit-name" i.e using "url" of image as name on "source" and "taget" . Don't do any "notifiyChanged" like functions after return from detail to list.

Comment: @TeeTracker : Tried this way too. Still no results. I have a viewpager, Upon that inflating main fragment, Viewpager is hosted on main fragment. Viewpager has 3 other fragment. Now, Navigating from fragment (one hosted from viewpager fragments) to another (new fragment) will shared transition forward. but not coming backward. This is my scenario. Please Help!

Comment: Could you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution for this problem, all the magic below:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    postponeEnterTransition()
    vm.state.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer  {
        if (it == QuizListViewModel.State.Ready) {
            (view.parent as? ViewGroup)?.doOnPreDraw {
                startPostponedEnterTransition()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

If your view contains RecyclerView, you have to postpone animation till list is filled and view renderered. More about that in this very helpful post ❤️  [Fragment Transitions by Chris Banes](https://chris.banes.dev/2018/02/18/fragmented-transitions/)